# GTK3 menu empty

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to show a popup menu in my GTK3 application after clicking a button. The problem is that the menu is empty after clicking.

My code is:

```
GtkWidget *main_menu;
GtkWidget *main_menu_new;
GtkWidget *main_menu_save;
GtkWidget *main_menu_load;

gboolean main_menu_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event,
    gpointer user_data)
{
  gtk_menu_popup_at_widget(GTK_MENU(main_menu), widget,
               GDK_GRAVITY_SOUTH,
               GDK_GRAVITY_SOUTH, NULL);

  return TRUE;
}
```

In app activate event handler:

```
  main_menu_new = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("New file");
 
  main_menu_save = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Save file");
  main_menu_load = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Load file");


  main_menu = gtk_menu_new();
  
  gtk_menu_attach(GTK_MENU(main_menu), main_menu_new, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  gtk_menu_attach(GTK_MENU(main_menu), main_menu_save, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  gtk_menu_attach(GTK_MENU(main_menu), main_menu_load, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  
  menu_button = gtk_button_new();
  gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(menu_button), "Menu");

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(menu_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(main_menu_clicked), NULL);
```

Comment: `gtk_menu_attach` has the following checks: `g_return_if_fail (left_attach < right_attach);
  g_return_if_fail (top_attach < bottom_attach);` thus your items aren't added

Comment: By the way, it should have printed warnings to console